# XSD elements with the same name under the same depth

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a question whether this XSD snippet is valid:

```
<xsd:element name="yolo" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element name="yolo" />
```

example XML:

```
<yolo />
```

thanks

Comment: @Digital_Reality, this is not a duplicate of the post you've pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer, the snippet is not valid.

Let's say that you put the above snippet in the following context (to make it clear what do you mean by the same depth, since @Janty got confused by it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="test">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="yolo" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="yolo" />         
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Assuming you try to above with a .NET XSD processor, you would get the following error:

> Multiple definition of element 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd:yolo'
>   causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be
>   formed such that during validation of an element information item
>   sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly
>   therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in
>   turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or
>   attributes of that item, and without any information about the items
>   in the remainder of the sequence.

If you try with a Xerces-based processor...

> cos-nonambig: "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd":yolo and
>   "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd":yolo (or elements from their
>   substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During
>   validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those
>   two particles.

The XSD spec describes cos-nonambig [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#cos-nonambig) (more or less Microsoft's implementation error message).

However, to add to the confusion, some processors allow you to override the UPA behaviour (specifically or indirectly), so it might very well happen to try the same and get no error... Microsoft does it with [EnableUpaCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemacompilationsettings.enableupacheck%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) and Xerces with their [schema-full-checking](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#validation.schema-full-checking) feature.

Microsoft documentation applies in your case... this is their example... matching, isn't it?

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: very detailed comment which helped me alot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For `<yolo />`

you should have the below schema

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="yolo" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Please use the online tools to generate schema to xml or xml to schema as [XSD2XML](http://www.xsd2xml.com/) and [XML2XSD](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output)

Comment: Thanks, but i do not wish to compose my XSD on behalf of the example XML provided. 
I am writing some kind of a tool to validate XSD, and i wish to know - if my tool will get the above XSD , is it considered valid?
I do know i could write a "better" XSD for this example. but thats not my point. thanks

Comment: Ok, Then you should go through the basics of xsd development http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp. It will help you to create your correct schema.